# Creating a Hoverable DropDown Menu with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, flexbox

I am currently following the youtube video below which demonstrates how to build a hoverable dropdown menu, utilizing HTML and CSS.

Youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Qrs8p7WgCc

I have copied the code and reviewed his video several times; still with different results. My only assumption is that his HTML/CSS version is outdated as his video is from 2017. The difference is apparent when we both create {display:flex} under "nav ul" in our CSS.

## Video Output After {display:Flex}

[image]

## Video End Results

[image]

## My Output After {display:flex}

[image]

## My End Results

[image]

## My index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="menu">
        <a href="#" class="brand"><img src="#" alt=""></a>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">List 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">List 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">List 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <section></section>
</body>
</html>
```

## My styles.css

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(bg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}

.menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    padding: 0 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.menu img {
    float: left;
    width: 84px;
}

nav {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}

nav ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: flex;
}

nav ul li { 
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 30px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li ul {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    min-width: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: .5s;
    transform: translateY(40px);
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateY(0px);
}

nav ul li ul li a {
padding: 10px;
}
```

His source code should be the same - the short video above can be used for reference. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You've got a css rule that's looking for a nested relationship. nav > ul > li > ul

```
nav ul li:hover ul {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

But your html doesn't have that relationship

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List 3</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Your nested `<ul>` is a sibling of the `<li>`, not a child. You probably want the next sibling selector `+`

```
nav ul li:hover + ul {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed quite a few things in the video. Please look below and compare to your own code. You wrapped the list items wrong among forgetting other values to the CSS file.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(bg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  padding: 0 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.menu img {
  float: left;
  width: 84px;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 33px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #184771;
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul li ul {
  display: block;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  min-width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

nav ul li ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="menu">
      <a href="#" class="brand"><img src="#" alt="" /></a>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">List 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Pages</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">List 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">List 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <section></section>
  </body>
</html>
```